# Clojure Domina Tutorial

Tags: clojure, closures, clojurescript

I've recently been reading up on Clojure webstack. I've gone through ring/enlive. Now, I need to learn about Google Closure / the Clojure bindings: https://github.com/levand/domina

However, I can't find a good domina tutorial anywhere. Is there a website that provides a guided tour for building web apps in domina?

(I'm familiar with Clojure + Java GUI -- the main thing I need is to learn how to build web apps.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before learning Domina you will need to learn ClojureScript. Check out : [ClojureScriptOne](http://clojurescriptone.com/)